# Is it correct to say, ' Please wait, the session was not yet started'

Tags: sentence-structure

I am translating from German to English. 
The scenario is: A screen sharing session is schedule and is not yet started. Someone tries to join this session.
What is the correct way to ask them to wait with a message?

> Please wait, the session **has not yet** been started.

OR

> Please wait, the session **was not yet** started.

OR

> Please wait, the session **is not yet** started.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the simplest is best:

"Please wait, the session has not started yet."

"...has not yet been..." is more complicated than necessary.

"...was not yet..." is not good, mixing past tense with the idea of something ongoing.

"...is not started..." is actually correct, but it does not sound as natural to use present tense with a past participle. "Your session is not running yet" would be a present-tense way to say it.

Comment: "The session has not been started yet" is okay when you want to emphasize that you're waiting for someone or something to start the session, rather than for the session itself to start. I agree that "The session has not started yet" is more natural in this context, and likely in general.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but none of your suggestions are correct:

> Please wait, the session has not yet been started.

.."has not yet been" just mixes up all kinds of tenses.

> Please wait, the session was not yet started.

.."was" is past tense. You wouldn't say "was not yet.." unless you were recounting a situation in the past. You would not say this when asking someone in the *present* to wait for something to start.

> Please wait, the session is not yet started.

..should be "has", not "it".

---

Instead you could write:

> Please wait, the session has not yet started
>
> Please wait, the session has not started yet
>
> Please wait, the session is about to start